# How can I get values from jquery-ui drag and resize functions?

Tags: jquery-ui

Here is jquery-ui's slider function:

```
  $("#x").slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 900,
      step: .1,
      values: [slidervalue2],
      slide: function (event, ui) {
          for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
              $("#y").val(ui["value"] + "%");
              $("#z").width(ui["value"] + "%");
          }
      }
  });
```

I can use numbers generated by the function by using the array address (if that's the correct term!)

```
(ui["value"])
```

I can set (ui["value"]) to a variable or whatever. How can I do the same for this jquery-ui function:

```
$(".z").draggable({
    stop: function () {
        var top = ui["value"];
        var left = ui["value"];
}
}).resizable({
    start: function () {

    },
    stop: function () {

        var width = ui["value"];
        var height = ui["value"];

    }
});
```

The draggable function operates by generating inline css rules 'top' and 'left'. I'd love to be able to set these values to the variables on lines 4 and 5 (var 'top' and var 'left' respectfully)

Could someone also explicity explain what:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
              $("#y").val(ui["value"] + "%");
              $("#z").width(ui["value"] + "%");
          }
```

Is doing? How does this allow the values to be used on the context of the slider function?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BG9r2/2/)

UPDATE

This may help:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example/

(at the bottom it refers to callback functions)

Comment: You have a `Syntax Error: on line 1` should be `$('#x')`

Comment: Was that your problem?